# Localization for AzureDevOps REST API

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I use the .NET SDK client (version 16.156.0-preview available on NuGet) to query Azure DevOps data by using REST API, but how can we manage localization labels in order to get labels in English, French or other languages ?

For example, when I get all workitem fields :

```cs
    var client = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
    var fields = await client.GetFieldsAsync(GetFieldsExpand.ExtensionFields);
    return fields.Select(e => new FieldDetail()
    {
        Name = e.Name,
        ReferenceName = e.ReferenceName
    }).ToList();
```

Is it possible to get Name in a specific culture ? (en-GB, fr-FR, …)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure devops rest api doesn't support to get a Name in a specific culture. But I think there is other workaround can help for your need.

There's a good library called localeplanet for Localization and Internationalization in JavaScript. Furthermore, I think it's native and has no dependencies to other libraries (e.g. jQuery)

Here's the website of library: http://www.localeplanet.com/

Also look at this article by Mozilla, you can find very good method and algorithms for client-side translation: http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2011/10/06/i18njs-internationalize-your-javascript-with-a-little-help-from-json-and-the-server/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer.
Did you know if there is only one culture used by default on AzuredevOps or if the default culture dépends on a AzureDevOps configuration ?